# OnPreRender Event Override in partial class

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, kentico, asp.net-4.5

I'm trying to override OnPreRender event using partial classes

first classes is from the Kentico CMS and I cannot change that classes since it's a default class in the CMS. Now I Want to override the default behavior of OnPreRender event in the first class fro the second class which is a custom class I created manually.

Class 1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using CMS.UIControls;
using CMS.ExtendedControls;
using CMS.PortalEngine;
using CMS.Helpers;

public partial class CMSPages_PortalTemplate : PortalPage
{

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);

        // Init the header tags
        //tags is a label
        tags.Text = HeaderTags;


        if (PortalContext.ViewMode.IsWireframe())
        {
            CSSHelper.RegisterWireframesMode(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Class 2

```
using CMS.UIControls;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;


public partial class CMSPages_PortalTemplate : PortalPage
{
    public CMSPages_PortalTemplate()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {   
        //Override behavior
        tags.Text = tags.Text + HeaderTags + "MyTest";
    }

}
```

Is this possible? I tried debugging, but it never hits the OnPreRender event of the second class

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're developing in ASPX mode, then you need to first create a master page template and then have your subsequent pages inherit from that masterpage.  From there your pages will hit that event.

Secondly, the class name is the same exact class name as the default portal page template. So this is probably another reason it's currently isn't being hit. Suprising it even runs with that in place.

Follow along with the [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/developing-websites/developing-websites-using-aspx-templates)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to override same method in partial class.

Instead of creating partial class inherit your cumtom class from CMSPages_PortalTemplate